# activatables.js tabing js sending values on URL

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script src=" /js/activatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  activatables('tab', ['page-1', 'page-2', 'page-3', 'page-4', 'page-5', 'page-6']);
</script>
```

I am using this js for tab in the table. But i am not able to remove the `#tab` from my URL.
Is there any way where this tab values like `#page=page-1` will not pass in the URL.

Comment: How is this related to PHP? Your tabs are using an anchor (which you can't read via PHP). In case you want to remove use JavaScript inide the tab script (something like window.location.hash) or newer history.pushState.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

use this code

```
activatables('page', ['page-1', 'page-2', 'page-3', 'page-4', 'page-5', 'page-6']);
               ^
```

BTW this is not related to PHP..isn't it?